# Initialization Error in Cucumber-Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, frameworks, cucumber, bdd

I'm new to Frameworks, I choose BDD with cucumber,

Created two **Feature files**, two **Step definitions** and two **Test runners**. For Admin and Applicant Login functionality individually.

When I run with one login functionality it was successful, And I created for the second Login
Got Initialization Error.

```
cucumber.runtime.DuplicateStepDefinitionException: Duplicate step definitions in stepDefinitions.Login_Applicant_StepDef.the_URL() in file:/C:/Users/SSMP/eclipse-workspace/New%20folder/OptevusUI_BDD_Framework/target/classes/ and stepDefinitions.Login_Admin_StepDef.the_URL() in file:/C:/Users/SSMP/eclipse-workspace/New%20folder/OptevusUI_BDD_Framework/target/classes/
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeGlue.addStepDefinition(RuntimeGlue.java:33)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.addStepDefinition(JavaBackend.java:151)
D:\users\scw\Data\Versuche\2020-MPC-Diss_scw
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please pay a bit more attention to the description of your problem and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

There is issue in your folder name please edit folder name( For example if you name  your folder name as "Abc_def" in project that underscore take it as special character so you need to edit name as "AbcDef")

file:/C:/Users/SSMP/eclipse-workspace/New**%20**folder/OptevusUI_BDD_Framework/target/classes/ and stepDefinitions.Login_Admin_StepDef.the_URL() in file:/C:/Users/SSMP/eclipse-workspace/New**%20**folder/OptevusUI_BDD_Framework/target/classes/

Edit folder name and refresh project and rerun

Comment: Thankyou@ustin Lambert

Comment: If my answer usefull to you please accept my answer by tick green so others can get idea about this problem